# gmp_strval gmp_init error (converting ip addesses)

Tags: php, ip, gmp

I am getting an error with a bit of borrowed code I am using to get longitude and latitude from IP addresses. It has worked in the past - as recently as last week actually - but I'm getting an error caused by this line of code:

```
    return gmp_strval(gmp_init($ipv6long, 2), 10);
```

The problem appears to be coming from gmp_strval & gmp_init. Apparently, my shared server sometimes has the gmp library and sometimes not (I cannot image any other reason for the error as this was working before w/o any changes to the code).

This line is from the following function (which is, of course, part of a much longer file which I will not try to post here):

```
    private function ipv6Numeric($ipv6) {
       $ip_n = inet_pton($ipv6);
       $bits = 15;

       // 16 x 8 bit = 128bit
       $ipv6long = 0;

       while($bits >= 0){
           $bin = sprintf("%08b", (ord($ip_n[$bits])));

           if($ipv6long){
             $ipv6long = $bin . $ipv6long;
           }
           else{
             $ipv6long = $bin;
           }
           $bits--;
       }
       return gmp_strval(gmp_init($ipv6long, 2), 10);
      }
```

Essentially, I guess I am looking for some sort of alternative to that one line that does not require the gmp library. I really do not deal with stuff a lot, so I'm not exactly sure what is going on here. Any advice and/or enlightenment would be very much appreciated.